# Audio input device not switching automatically when I disconnect headset

Tags: pulseaudio, 20.04, microphone, headset

Whenever I connect my headset to the audio jack of my laptop I get a popup asking me whether I connected headphones, a headset or a mic.

Whenever I connect a headset, the microphone being used automatically changes to the headset mic as expected, but when I disconnect the headset, it should automatically change to the internal microphone but it is not happening. This was functioning properly on Ubuntu 19.10. So, every time I disconnect the headset, I have to go to sound settings to select the internal mic as the one to use.

How do I re-enable this behaviour?

Comment: A workaround I found is this extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/906/sound-output-device-chooser/